# Blogger JSON API Post fetch and Content Parse

Tags: javascript, regex, json, blogger

I'm new to Blogger and its JSON API. I've found out I can retrieve all posts / retrieve specific post using post id.

I'm trying to build a lazy loading blogger post list page, where blog content needs to fetch dynamically. What is the best way to retrieve latest 5 posts in every request? (I don't want to request 5 times for 5 posts)

Another thing is, I want to show post's first image on post list page. How can I fetch the first image and fetch textual content only?

I've searched Google but couldn't find any good tutorial. I hope you guys can help me.

Cheers

Comment: not sure if this help. http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/

Comment: Were you able to fetch textual content only?

Comment: Yes, I've done something similar. Its not fetching textual content its filtering textual contents.. You can find the implementations here. http://blog.thisismovement.co.uk/

Answer (score 2):

**One option is to use javascript callbacks , for example :**

http://jayunit100.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=myFunc

This will return back a peice of executable javascript code which

1) Calls a function which you defined
2) Sends that function a json object

**The below is my speculation on this matter, because it clearly is much more difficult than one might think it should be:**

It is not clear to me why a simpler, pure, authentication-free JSON REST api is not available (maybe one does exist), which simply takes a blog id and returns pure text, however, I suspect it might be that blogger wants to discourage crawling.

Answer (score 2):

http://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json

Replace `blogname` with you Blogname.

You will get JSON Object and use JSON FORMATTER to format the JSON.

Comment: Best answer ever. This is great but what if I want to search for articles from this json?? What if I want to get categories and their links?? In short any tutorial for this? Am using this but cant find material that will enable me to extract everything I need from feed. Help please